# How can I create specialized metadata nodes via llvm-c API?

Tags: llvm, debug-symbols

I'd like to add debugging information to a LLVM-generated code. I'm using LLVM C API (since I'm calling LLVM from Smalltalk via FFI).

Debug informations are attached via specialized metadata nodes, but I could not find any way to create them. By looking to LLVM source code, it seems that I'd need to create metadata node with certain kind (say DILocationKind) but the "kind" enum seems not exposed by LLVM-C API nor LLVMMDNode() allows for passing the "kind" as an argument.

Is there a way create specialized metadata nodes using LLVM-C API?
Could somebody point me to some example how to add debug information to LLVM-generated code using LLVM-C API?

Comment: The LLVM C API does not cover everything. Even if you go through FFI you can use the C++ API by wrapping the appropriate parts of it yourself in C. This is what projects like llvmlite (Python bindings) do

Comment: Yes, I'd rather like to avoid that if not necessary, but I'd have to do it if there's no way. Thanks!

Comment: The general reasoning behind it is that the C API is (at least) quasi stable and the metadata format has been in flux for the last few years while we're working on it. I haven't wanted to let it be exposed via the C API because it's not quite there yet. If you're willing to avoid stability guarantees then what Eli suggests in the best bet (and is what other projects are doing), otherwise you'll probably need to wait until it stabilizes more.